# Sci-Fi comedy - This is a job for the Boys

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a sci-fi comedy film probably from the 80s, it was a favourite of my Uncle but I've lost the name.

I think it is set in Australia, and there is a problem with aliens abducting and mutilating cattle.

The Prime Minister is deciding how to react with various advisors suggesting the army or air force, but the Prime Minister declares 'This is a job for The Boys' and uses a dedicated phone to summon (quoting my uncle) 'three lunatics in a van', who proceed to blow up everything in sight.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Bad Taste](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092610/?ref_=tt_urv), New Zealand, 1987.

Edited from IMDB:

> Four men known as "The Boys" get called into a quiet New Zealand
> fishing town to investigate reports of a UFO, only to run into
> malevolent zombie-like murderous townspeople. What follows is a
> gore-drenched real guy's movie. The great Peter Jackson got his start
> writing and directing his own movies with this amazing b-movie
> independent zombie / alien gore comedy.

Here's a [trailer](https://www.nzfilm.co.nz/films/bad-taste) courtesy of the New Zealand Film Commission.

Comment: If you enjoyed *Bad Taste*, you should watch *Brain Dead*, also by Jackson. *Meet the Feebles* is also great, but it'll ruin anyone's love for muppets.

Comment: i am intrigued. peter jackson is a genius.

Comment: After seeing *Brain Dead* (aka *Dead Alive*, which is so much fun. That lawnmower scene alone is incredible) and *Bad Taste*, it blows my mind even more that he got the "keys" and go-ahead to do a multi-multi-million dollar interpretation for Lord of the Rings.  I suppose those show his imagination, and ability to work with a low budget?  In any case, I agree that Peter Jackson is a genius.

Comment: I note that New Zealand doesn't have a president, so in that way the movie should be different from the queston.